# How to call bitly v4 api to shorten url using httpclient c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

So I want call Bitly API to shorten URL I am able to get response using POSTMAN and Jquery but not able to get response using C#.

[image]

Working Jquery Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".createBitly").on("click", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
        var accessToken = "550ea49c78208978cbeb85ef24XXXX49874cc097";

        var params = {
            "long_url": url
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(params)
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

C# Code I am trying but not able to achieve using C#:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "550ea49c78208978cbeb85ef24XXXX49874cc097");
            var content = new
            {
                long_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
            };
            var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
            
            //HTTP POST
            var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", model);
            postTask.Wait();

            var result = postTask.Result;

        }
```

Now getting response success but not getting data actually want.

[image]

I want response like getting in Postman

[image]

How to achieve this using C# any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: "but not able to achieve" - can you please elaborate? what exactly is the trouble? do you get any error messages? (and side note: it's better to use `await` thant `.Result`)

Comment: seems to me that [`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0) already serialises the content. so try passing `content` instead of the serialised `model`

Comment: Also, you may consider injecting an HttpClient instead of `using` a new one over and over. _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application."_ - [Remarks in Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution way back sorry not posted hope it would be helpful.

```
public static class BitlyShortUrl
{

    private readonly static string _token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BitlyToken"].ToString();

    public static string ShortenAsync(string longUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"long_url\":\"" + longUrl + "\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
                    return jsonResponse.link;
                }
                else if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
                    return jsonResponse.link;
                }
                else
                {
                    return longUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code you shared above.

**1. Authorization Header**

```
// This line of code ends up adding an incorrect header that looks like this: 
// Authorization: Authorization Bearer <myAccessToken>
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<myAccessToken>");

// Instead, try this
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer <myAccessToken>");
```

**2. Request Body**
PostAsJsonAsync serializes the 2nd parameter into a json.  So, you should not serialize the `content`.  Instead send the object named `content` as the second parameter.

Below is sample code that I tried and it works:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {myAccessToken}");

var content = new
{
    long_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
};
        
//HTTP POST
var resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", content);
Console.WriteLine(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```